Transit in Riyadh
I'm British national and transiting through Riyadh, flying with Saudia Airline. I bought a ticket through other online platform. My transit time is exact 12 hours on Riyadh airport at Terminal 4. My connecting flight is at Terminal 4. Do I need transit visa?

Can you confirm that both flights are on the same ticket?

The one potentially interesting angle here as that you don't need a visa for connections under 12 hours, while the OP's is apparently exactly 12 hours. But since their flights are Saudia, they qualify for the 96 hour free visa.

Or just get a e-visa which British citizens are eligible for...
